# Regex to Match a single or multiple email addresses separated by comma

Tags: regex

I need to have a regex pattern that matches the following kind of string

`#keyword1 a@b.com` or `#keyword2 a@b.com;b@c.com;d@e.com`

The following regex pattern doesn't do exactly what I want:

```
/(#)(?:keyword1|keyword2)\s([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)/g
```

The above regex expression only matches `#keyword1 a@b.com` correctly.
But for the second it matches everything before the first semicolon. I need it to match the entire thing. How can I do that please?

Comment: @heemayl I don't get what you mean but the regex pattern has been tested to match just about any email pattern: .com, .co.uk, .net etc.

Comment: Put it in parentheses and it will match them all: https://regex101.com/r/kC6vJ2/1

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for responding. But that's not what I'm looking for. I have restated the question in the post to make you understand my requirement.

Comment: _"the regex pattern has been tested to match just about any email pattern"_ - [this is worth a read](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: @JamesThorpe That still doesn't solve my problem. And the pattern I'm using is per RFC2822 standards.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve the problem - it's just a comment that email regexes are _hard_ - and chances are you'll probably refuse a valid one at some point.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I understand. But what matters most to me is a solution to the current problem I have. Can you help?

Comment: Can you edit and include an example of the matches you *do* want and add some tags for your environment/regex flavour

Comment: @AlexK. based on my question I need something that would match either this: `#keyword1 a@b.com` or `#keyword1 a@b.com;c@d.com` or all strings that look like that. In the case of the one with the two emails, it can be three or more (multiple). I hope you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest parsing the string in two steps. First distinguish the keyword from the array of email addresses and then split the array.

First retrieve both the keyword and the arrray, assuming that is all that the string consists of. I'm using the JavaScript RegExp notation, but you should be able to understand what is happening.

Assume the string is "#keyword2 a@b.com;b@c.com;d@e.com".

```
/^#(keyword1|keyword2) (.*)$/g
```

Group 1 will be "keyword2" and group 2 will be "a@b.com;b@c.com;d@e.com". Now apply the following pattern to group 2 and loop through the matches to retrieve each email address.

```
/([^;]*)(?:;|$)/g
```

This pattern makes no assumptions about whether or not the email addresses are properly formatted, just that they are separated by a semicolon. This also works if there's only a single email address.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but it gave me a huge lead to the solution I need. Many thanks!!!